# LINQ lazy loading and creating new object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a few classes,

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Genre genre { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist artist { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Album> albums { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistResponse
{
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AlbumResponse
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Genre genre { get; set; }
    public ArtistResponse artist { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to download all albums with Artists, and return it with AlbumResponse. 
I have a LINQ expression

```
return ctx.Albums.Include(i => i.artist).Select(i => new AlbumResponse
            {
                AlbumId = i.AlbumId,
                artist = new ArtistResponse {  Name=i.artist.Name, ArtistId=i.artist.ArtistId},
                genre = i.genre,
                Title = i.Title
            }).ToList();
```

So I'm including 'artist' by "Include()" and then creating new AlbumResponse where I create new ArtistResponse. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. It throws an InvalidOperationException. "i.artist.ArtistId" is a null, I don't know why, without ArtistId  initialization works everything fine, with only "Name=i.artist.Name" works perfectly.

How do I attach ArtistId to 'artist' in 'AlbumResponse'?
Exception: "The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type"
Classes Album and Artist are in Database, AlbumId and ArtistId are non-nullable. ArtistResponse and AlbumResponse are just "extra" classes for adding or getting info from database, so ArtistId and AlbumId in "*Response" are just ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ArtistId` column of the `artist` navigation property is a `Nullable<int>` and the type of the `ArtistId` property of the `ArtistResponse` type is `int` you should check whether there is a value returned:

```
return ctx.Albums.Include(i => i.artist).Select(i => new AlbumResponse
{
    AlbumId = i.AlbumId,
    artist = new ArtistResponse { Name = (i.artist != null) ? i.artist.Name : string.Empty, ArtistId = (i.artist != null && i.artist.ArtistId.HasValue) ? artist.ArtistId.Value : 0 },
    genre = i.genre,
    Title = i.Title
}).ToList();
```

This is obviously just a guess since you havent't posted the definitions of your types nor the actual error message you are getting.

**Edit:**

What if you change the type of the `ArtistId` property of the `ArtistResponse` type to `Nullable<int>` (`int?`):

```
public class ArtistResponse
{
    public Nullable<int> ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it shows error on "HasValue", "int does not contain a definition for hasValue...".

Comment: Try to make the ArtistId property of the ArtistResponse class nullable as per my edit.

Comment: It works now :) but I don't really understand why.. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: You can't set the value of an int to null because int is a non-nullable value type. But a Nullable<int> may be set to either null or an int value.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
return ctx.Albums.Include(i => i.artist).Select(i => new AlbumResponse
            {
                AlbumId = i.AlbumId,
                artist = new ArtistResponse {  Name=i.artist.Name, ArtistId=i.artist.ArtistId ?? 0( or Guid.NewGuid() << or this if you decide to use guid type)}, 
                genre = i.genre,
                Title = i.Title
            }).ToList();
```

You have to assign a unique number/key to your artist id, if you dont want to default that to zero. new guid perhaps?you gotta find a way to create a unique int id.

Answer (score 1):

You may, I am not saying you do without complete knowledge, have an incomplete projection.  Entity is kind of weird about data in that it is not realized for use out of the gate till it is an official object.  EG: Your where, select, and others extension syntaxes don't work yet as the object is not yet realized.

You may wish to try something as simple as:

```
return ctx.Albums.Include(i => i.artist)
```

**.ToList()**

```
.Select(i => new AlbumResponse
            {
                AlbumId = i.AlbumId,
                artist = new ArtistResponse {  Name= i?.artist?.Name ?? String.Empty, ArtistId=i?.artist?.ArtistId ?? 0},
                genre = i.genre,
                Title = i.Title
            }).ToList();
```

Else the projection may not be realized for it's navigation property 'artist'.  ToList() is the poor man's way to realize a projection fast and essentially say: ".NET this is okay as a legitimate object collection now".  You can use other extensions I believe like 'First' I believe as well. This is just a guess but I know I have worked with EF for a while and 'realization' when doing load events, math, and other things is often the culprit.  Or it could be as others have stated that you are simply getting a null reference to the navigation and it blows up.  I did some pseudo code with a ?. conditional operator(basically checks through the chain for nulls without blowing if the parent is null as well) then a coalescing null operator '??' to say if this thing is null assign a default.